# select l[x] from vector where (l[x] - l[x-1]) > 1

Tags: r

I have list `l`:

```
l_in <- c(1:5, 8, 11:13, 17)
```

I want to select `l_in[x]` element from this list where `(l_in[x] - l_in[x-1]) > 1`

So the output should be:

```
   l_out <- c(8, 11, 17)
```

Furthermore I would also like to include element from `l_in` which is before first `l_out` element, so the output should be:

```
   l_out2 <- c(5, 8, 11, 17)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we could try:

```
delta <- diff(l_in) > 1
c(l_in[which(delta)[1]], l_in[c(FALSE, delta)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there should be 13 in `l_out`? Anyway try this.

```
l_in <- c(1:5, 8, 11:13, 17)
l_out <- c()
for(i in 2:length(l_in)) {
  if (l_in[i] - l_in[i-1] > 1) l_out <- c(l_out,l_in[i])
}
l_out <- c(l_in[which(l_in == l_out[1]) - 1],l_out)
l_out
[1]  5  8 11 17
```